# GA3 Site Speed Report in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

Trying to find GA3 Site Speed report in GA4.

Tried to create a report but unable to find any metric closer to it

Checked in avauilable reports and also tried creating in explore section

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There are no speed-related dimensions or metrics built into GA4. You would have to gather that data yourself. Say by adding custom metrics to the page_view event. And then create your own custom report.

The PerformanceNavigationTiming interface provides access to lots of timing information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming

The Core Web Vitals includes LCP, which is speed based. There is a library to help you get that:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals

And there are a few articles out there on gathering the Core Web Vitals in GA4, exporting the data to BigQuery, and then reporting on it in Looker Studio. Including one from me